# iOS 6.1 compatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a iOS 7.0 app, I need it run perfectly on iOS 6.1. I have download the iOS 6.1 simulator, and I have the iOS 7.0 sdk as the base sdk. If I want my app to run perfectly both on iOS 7.0 and iOS 6.1 do I have to set the base sdk as 6.1? or keep iOS 7.0 as the base sdk and just run this app using iOS 6.1 simulator. I know I should the set the deployment target as iOS 6.1 so It can work on iOS 6.1. I just don't know how to set the base sdk. Can anybody explain me the base sdk and deployment target?

Answer (score 3):

The **base SDK** defines which functionality you can use in your apps. As of today 2014-03-31, you can't submit applications that have a Base SDK set to iOS 6 anymore. You need to compile your apps with the 7.0 base SDK.

The **deployment target** describes the lowest iOS version your app will run on, so in your case it's 6.0.

If you're using iOS 7-only features, you'll have to **implement runtime checks**, largely based on `-respondsToSelector:`. That'll allow you to gracefully degrade on old versions.

Comment: So, I just set the deployment target as iOS 6.1. It will check if my app works fine on both versions? Do I need the add iOS 6.1 sdk to Xcode?

Comment: It won't check if your app works fine. You have to check it yourself. It's usually a lot of layout related work since the structure of the status bar and navigation bars changed completely between 6 and 7.

Comment: You don't need to include previous SDKs. They are kind of backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Set the base SDK to be always the latest, be it `7.0` or `7.1`. Your app is compiled using that sdk and therefore newer SDK compatibility and functions are applied to your project.

setting Min Deployment target allows compiler to check for API methods compatibility with that OS version in mind.

Hope it clears up your doubts.